# How would I call :parent for this tooltip?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to attach a Jquery tooltip to a table `tr` tag. However, I can't get it to work on the `tr` as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7LaQQ/). If I were to say add the `class` and `title` tags to the `td` elements, how would I apply the `:parent` to the css so that a tooltip would show when howevered anywhere on the row?

Currently, I am using this which doesn't work

```
<tr class="normalTip" title="Hello, I am aToolTip">
```

And this works without an issue

```
<a href="#" class="normalTip" title="Hello, I am aToolTip">Normal Tooltip</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
$('a.normalTip').parent().aToolTip();
```

---

I tried this and it worked.

```
$('tr').aToolTip();
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LaQQ/2/

---

#### Adding to more selectors:

Use this way:

```
$('tr, a').aToolTip();
```

or if you are using class way, then

```
$('.normalTip').aToolTip();
```

Comment: Great, thank you! If I wanted to turn the tooltip on the `a` tag as well, would I run `.aToolTip();` multiple times with the different tag?

Comment: Use this way: `$('tr, a').aToolTip();`, or if you are using class way, then `$('.normalTip').aToolTip();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get parent of current element

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7LaQQ/3/)**

```
$('a.normalTip').parent().aToolTip();
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do this

```
$('.normalTip').aToolTip();
```

This will initiate all instance which will have `.normal` css class. And then it would not matter the tag is an `a` or `tr` or anything else.